# Conflict in relative file name path in eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, relative-path, absolute-path

In my application I am reading an XML file(say ABC.xml) which is in the WebContent/META-INF folder  and parsing it using DOM parser
as below

```
File xmlFile = new File("WebContent//META-INF//ABC.xml");
parser.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(xmlFile.getAbsolutePath())));
```

Its showing file not found exception and when I print the xmlFile.getAbsolutePath() Its showing

```
D:\Softwares\SDE_7\eclipse\WebContent\META-INF\ABC.xml
```

This is where my eclipse setup is located

So I tried to use the same logic in simple java program  and print the absolute path where it shows
the correct path(project folder structure) and the program works fine

```
D:\GME_WorkSpace\Practice_1\WebContent\META-INF\sample.xml
```

Why is this conflict? How can I rectify it?

Comment: WebContent is the directory where eclipse, your development environment, stores the sources of your webapp. In procution, this directory won't exist. All you'll have is a war file containing the files of the deployed application, and a file system.

Comment: Is **WebContent** your Context-Root folder? If thats the case, you can leave it out of your relative path. also why do you have double forward slashes in your name path? you only use them if you have back slashes

Comment: I am getting this error in development environment only.Can you please explain why this conflict occurs?

Comment: @greenkode WebContent is not my root folder.The program executes in the same manner if I use double/single forward slashes

Comment: hmm, thats interesting, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about WebContent, it sounds like you've written a Servlet.

In that case you should be using ServletContext to find your files.

getServletContext().getRealPath(...) will get the full OS path for a relative file name in your Servlet.

getServletContext() can be called from any class that inherits from HttpServlet.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("WebContent//META-INF//ABC.xml");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```